# Can´t stop/pause embedded youtube video (youtube api) inside lightbox by closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I´m working on a Lightbox, where user can watch videos.
The Problem if i would close it by clicking outside of the container i will get the error "Cannot read property 'stopVideo' of undefined" but if i close it with the button, it works well.

```
    $(function(){
        var appendthis =  ("look over jsfiddle");
        $('a[data-modal-id]').click(function(e) {
        $(window).resize();
        e.preventDefault();
        $("body").append(appendthis);
        $(".modal-overlay").fadeTo(500, 0.7);
        var modalBox = $(this).attr('data-modal-id');
        $('#'+modalBox).fadeIn($(this).data());

        $(".js-modal-close-vid, .modal-overlay").click(function() { 
            var player = $(this).closest('.modal-box').data('player');
            player.stopVideo();
                $(".modal-box, .modal-overlay").fadeOut(500, function() {
                $(".modal-overlay").remove();
                });
        });

    });
```

**JsFiddle in the comment.**

Comment: JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4f5dksj5/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".js-modal-close, .modal-overlay").click(function() {
  var player = $('.modal-box').data('player');
  player.stopVideo();
  player.seekTo(0);
  $(".modal-box, .modal-overlay").fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(".modal-overlay").remove();
  });
});
```

The change was changing `$(this).closest('.modal-box').data('player');` to `$('.modal-box').data('player')` and it works. I think the problem here was incorrect use of the `closest` method and the selector not being what you expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/4f5dksj5/6/

Comment: Please describe what you changed or add internal documentation.

Comment: No this doesn´t work, because there are more videos and your solution works just for the first video. But you found out the problem. If i click outside the container the video isn´t the closest more. How can i fix it ?

Comment: @pytth I tried to split it up like .js-modal-close{code} and .modal-overlay{code} but i don´t know how to find the video in the lighbox..

Comment: Can you please provide me with a gist of the full code for this or is what you posed here pretty much it?